# How to check weather item exist in JSON before being pushed

Tags: angularjs, json

Am trying to implement offline add to cart functionality.

Here I have the add to cart function.

```
    $scope.payloadData = [];

    $scope.add_to_cart = function(MRP, ProductId, ProductVariantId) {

  $scope.dt = {  //It is JSON string
      "Unitprice": MRP,
      "ProductId": ProductId,
      "Productvariantid": ProductVariantId
 }

//If user is not logged in                  
if(localStorage.getItem('tokenvalue') != undefined) {
   $scope.payloadData.push($scope.dt);                      
   for(var i=0;i<$scope.payloadData.length;i++) {
   $scope.cmp = angular.equals($scope.payloadData, $scope.payloadData); 
  if($scope.cmp == "false") { // Not working
    $scope.payloadData.push($scope.dt); //Push if item not exist in $scope.payloadData
   }
  else{ //do nothing }                      
}    
}

$scope.payloaddata after pushed is ://It is JSON array
[
    {
        "Unitprice": 500,
        "ProductId": 3,         
        "Productvariantid": 3
    }
]
```

How to check weather $scope.dt & $scope.payloadData data are same before being pushed.

Comment: You can use `indexOf` function for this. `if($scope.payloaddata.indexOf($scope.dt) == -1){ ...}`

Comment: do you want to check if $scope.dt is already present in $scope.payloaddata array?

Comment: Exately. I want to check before being pushed.

Comment: @Handi Not working..

Answer (score 0):

use hasOwnProperty method to determine that

```
**myObj.hasOwnProperty(newproperty to push)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using only primitive data types in your object. This is one way of checking if $scope.dt is already present in $scope.payloaddata

```
function containsObject(objStr, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(list[i]) === objStr) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var dtStr = JSON.stringify($scope.dt);
containsObject(dtStr, $scope.payloaddata);
```